# How can I restore photos from my ipad?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, photos.app

My computer -- with its attendant photo library -- was stolen, and now the only copy I have of many pictures is on my ipad. How can I transfer those photos to my new mac?

I tried the instructions from [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3838254?start=0&tstart=0) but these only found photos in the "Saved Photos" album, not all photos.

Comment: Have you tried to open iPhoto and then to import them from the device?

Comment: Yes; iPhoto only shows the same ones -- the ones in the Saved Photos album, not the 2700 other photos.

Answer (score 1):

You need a 3rd party app like

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24832/ipod-access-photo

(there are others, search Macupdate)

Note that the images will have been optimised for the iOS device so they may not ne as large as the ones on your Mac.

regards

Comment: Would you happen to be able to identify one that isn't scumware? I have a vigorous distrust of software that sells using those "free trial" services.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand the term "scumware" and I just rely on other people's reviews of the apps and by trialling them myself. Not sure what a '"free trial" service' is either, and you can get help for your vigorous mistrust issue, but not on a web site

Answer (score 0):

I would use [phoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) I have tried other programs out there but none of them are like phoneView. It allows you access to everything on your phone. You can take photos, music, etc off of your phone on to your computer or visa versa. Definitely the app I would use.